# Session Expired or Invalid in Apex Rest while calling GET Request:

Tags: apex, apexrest

I am getting the below error:

[image]

This is the access_token I am getting successfully. I make sure as soon as I get the access_token, I used that while calling GET Request, please guide.

[image]

Comment: Images are really a poor fit for this community. Can you include a text description of what you tried and the errors you faced? This question is virtually unsearchable and provides far less value than it otherwise would.

Comment: Agree. Believe me some questions needs screen shots for better understanding. Not every issue is same. So please bare with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, I should not be using : (colon), after the Bearer word, it should be space and `access_token`. Done !!

[image]